# Mongoose aggregate: keep original array and unwind with different field name

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to keep following document,

> { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1",  dimensions: [ { "k": "l", "v": 25} , {
>   "k": "w", "v": 10 }, { "k": "uom", "v": "cm" } ] }

but need to add one more field for all three array elements so above document would be returned as:

> { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1",  dimensions: [ { "k": "l", "v": 25} ,
>   { "k": "w", "v": 10 }, { "k": "uom", "v": "cm" } ], dimension:{ "k":
>   "l", "v": 25}  } // here dimension contains first array element
>
> { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1",  dimensions: [ { "k": "l", "v": 25} , {
>   "k": "w", "v": 10 }, { "k": "uom", "v": "cm" } ], dimension:{ "k":
>   "w", "v": 10 }  }// here dimension contains second array element
>
> { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1",  dimensions: [ { "k": "l", "v": 25} , {
>   "k": "w", "v": 10 }, { "k": "uom", "v": "cm" } ], dimension:{ "k":
>   "uom", "v": "cm" }  }// here dimension contains third array element

***Could you help me on this?***

Answer (score 1):

Add following steps to the pipeline:

```
[
   ....
   { $addFields: { dimension: "$dimensions" } },
   { $unwind: "$dimension" }
]
```

Not sure how `$arrayToObject` is related to the question though. The answer is based purely on the input and expected output snippets.

Comment: modified the question. Thank you for your help!